# carmen-rails subregion select (combine Canadian provinces and US states)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carmen

I have a dropdown with US states and territories.  I would like to add Canadian provinces so that the entire list is states/provinces in alphabetical order.

Currently I have this code which lists all US states and territories:

```
= extra_fields.input :province, label: "Franchisee Billing State/Province", input_html: { class: "form-control" } do
    = extra_fields.subregion_select(:province, "US", {prompt: 'Please select a state'}, required: 'region required')
```

I tried converting the second parameter of subregion_select to ["US, "CA"] but that breaks things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you are looking for union of Canadian provinces and US states for a `select` field without `country_select` functionality. If am i right, you can get by this way

```
countries = Carmen::Country.all.select{|c| %w{US CA}.include?(c.code)} # get the countries
# get the subregions of US and CA
subregions = countries.collect {|x| x.subregions }.flatten
```

In rails application

**Create helper method**

```
def subregions_of_us_and_canada
  countries = Carmen::Country.all.select{|c| %w{US CA}.include?(c.code)}
  # get subregions and sort in alphabetical order  
  countries.collect {|x| x.subregions }.flatten.sort_by(&:name)
end
```

**Call the above method in form**

```
= extra_fields.input :province, as: :select, collection: subregions_of_us_and_canada, label_method: :name, value_method: :code, label: "Franchisee Billing State/Province", input_html: { class: "form-control" }, prompt: 'Please select a state'
```

I hope this would be helpfull

Comment: I don't understand where `label_method: :name, value_method: :code` come from and what they do?

Comment: I hope you are using `simple_form`. `label_method` and `value_method` come with `simple_form`. The `lebel_method` for `<option>Label</option>` and `value_method` for `<option  value="value"></option>`. So if your `subregion` name is `Alabama` and code is `AL` then it becomes `<option value="AL">Alabama</option>`. For more details please inspect you `select` field and see their `options`.